# How to Convert Play 2.1 Async Method to Play 2.3 Promise

Tags: java-8, akka, java-7, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to upgrade a PlayFramework Project to the current version, and I'm having trouble converting one of the return signatures we had before.

Previously (Play 2.1 / Java 1.7) we had a controller method that built a sequence of Photo objects as promises, and then combined the results at the end for an async response:

```
// Combine all promises into a single promise
Promise<List<Photo>> promises =  Promise.sequence(eachPromisedPhoto.toArray(new Promise[0]));

// Return
return async(
  promises.map(
    new Function<List<Photo>, Result>() {
      public Result apply(List<Photo> photos) {
        List<String> MD5s = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Photo photo : photos) {
          if (photo != null && photo.isValid()) {
            MD5s.add(photo.toString());
          }
        }
        ObjectNode resultFinal = Json.newObject();
        if (MD5s.size() > 0) {
          resultFinal.put("MD5s", Json.toJson(MD5s));
          resultFinal.put("status", "OK");
        }
        else {
          resultFinal.put("status", "KO");
        }
        return ok(resultFinal);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

The async method no longer is available in Play 2.3+, as far as I can tell, and it's unclear how to properly convert over this return signature to the new approach.  We are also updating to Java 1.8, so usage of lambda expressions would be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Here's the modified code:

```
// Combine all promises into a single promise
Promise<List<Photo>> promises = Promise.sequence(eachPromisedPhoto);

// Return
return promises.map(
  new Function<List<Photo>, Result>() {
    public Result apply(List<Photo> photos) {
      List<String> MD5s = new ArrayList<>();
      photos.stream().filter(photo -> photo != null && photo.isValid()).forEach(photo -> {
        MD5s.add(photo.toString());
      });
      ObjectNode resultFinal = Json.newObject();
      if (MD5s.size() > 0) {
        resultFinal.put("pathSums", Json.toJson(MD5s));
        resultFinal.put("status", "OK");
      }
      else {
        resultFinal.put("status", "KO");
        resultFinal.put("message", "No results returned");
      }
      return ok(resultFinal);
    }
  }
);
```

The other key bit was the prior return signature was a basic `Result` for the controller method, and that had to be updated to `Promise<Result>` instead.  If you have any steps in your controller that don't return a promise, it's easier to make one, like this:

```
return Promise.promise(() -> badRequest(result));
```